# How to apply quote character on every field using custom CsvPreference

Tags: java, supercsv

I'm using super csv https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/apidocs/org/supercsv/prefs/CsvPreference.html 
to create csv file.

It works great. But I need to set quotes around all fields, not only those that have a comma. So instead of

```
1,2,test,"something,test", 1,x
```

I need this

```
"1","2","test","something,test","1","x"
```

**Question: WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE TO MAKE IT WORK???????????**

```
    private static final CsvPreference PIPE_DELIMITED = 
       new CsvPreference.Builder(WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE TO MAKE IT WORK???????????).build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
private static final CsvPreference PIPE_DELIMITED = 
       new CsvPreference.Builder(CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE)
                        .useQuoteMode(new AlwaysQuoteMode()
                        .build();
```

Comment: Thank you this definitely works. But I was curious if there is a way to do this by feeding chars like this `new CsvPreference.Builder('"', '|', "\n").build();` without a subfunction. Is there any combination of chars i can feed toachieve this? Or do I have to use a subfunction

Comment: I am afraid that is the only option you have. There are only two constructors 1) Builder(char quoteChar, int delimiterChar, String endOfLineSymbols)
where you can choose which quote/delimeter- char should be used and 2) Builder(CsvPreference preference)
where quote- delimeter chars and lineend symbols are predefined by an existing CsvPreference instance